# Multiple data exchange with a client on a TCP server

Tags: java, ssl

I'm making a java client and server comunicating through tcp with ssl. In order to exchange information with a tcp client-server conection. I've thought two options:

1. Create a new socket for each transmision of data from the client. Get the info and kill the thread that is running that socket.
2. Create a new socket when client connects, and then keep the input and output stream opened for data sharing while the user session is opened.

I think option 2 is the best. But I don't know how to "pause" the streams or get data from them after the first exchange. In the code you have the method that threads run for each new client. Does anybody have an idea about how to solve this question ? Thanks

```java
//SERVER SIDE CODE TO MANAGE THE STREAMS

public Threaded(SSLSocket s) {
        socket = s;
        System.out.println("New Thread started for "+s.getInetAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            socket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 out.println(inputLine);
                 System.out.println("server get: "+inputLine);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread err: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Closing thread....");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `I don't know how to "pause" the streams or get data from them after the first exchange`, why not send another request and get another response through the stream? It sounds like you're creating your own communication protocol. Alternatively you could just use HTTP as your protocol.

Comment: In that case, it is creating a new ssl tunnel every connection, it isn't wrong do that ?

Comment: Don't create a new connection, just keep the same connection open and communicate over it.

Comment: I understand, but I can't figure how to implement that

Comment: Like I said, you would be creating your own message protocol. If you don't want to do that, then simply use an existing protocol like HTTP.

Comment: Okey, but I'll probably go with option two. Something like reading the stream untill client sends some "endline" will probably work. Thank you :D

Comment: Yes, doing something like that is using your own protocol.

Comment: I'm very excited about that idea